# How to copy struct content in MATLAB into another struct, where the even index contents are same as odd index content

Tags: matlab

I am trying to copy the content of one array of struct into another in the below format:

For eg, I have:

```
A(1).Name = 'abc'
A(1).Val  =  1
A(2).Name = 'def'
A(2).Val  =  2
A(3).Name = 'ghi'
A(3).Val  =  3
A(4).Name = 'jkl'
A(4).Val  =  4
```

Now I need to copy the contents of A into B in the below format:

```
B(1).Name = 'abc'
B(1).Val  =  1
B(2).Name = 'abc'
B(2).Val  =  1
B(3).Name = 'def'
B(3).Val  =  2
B(4).Name = 'def'
B(4).Val  =  2
B(5).Name = 'ghi'
B(5).Val  =  3
B(6).Name = 'ghi'
B(6).Val  =  3
B(7).Name = 'jkl'
B(7).Val  =  4
B(8).Name = 'jkl'
B(8).Val  =  4
```

Is there a way in MATLAB to achieve this without loops?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know exactly what the purpose of `B` is so I will propose 2 solutions

1)

```
B = A;
B(end+1:end+length(A)) = A
```

2)

```
B = repmat(A,2,1)
```

The first solution is good if you want to add fields from A into A again (but says B since that was the wanted answer. The other solution is good if you want to create a new variable B that is the same as A in the beginning and the second half is a copy of the first half. The function `repmat` copies a matrix (or vector, or scalar) NxM times in the given direction.